# A way to continue a mailing that was cancelled?

Tags: civimail

Currently when a mailing is scheduled if we see a change that is needed, we have to cancel the mailing, then reuse it, fix the mistake, and send it again. Then we have to delete the original if we want to get it out of the interface.

Is there a way to simply "Continue" the cancelled mailing to save a few steps and avoid creating a duplicate and cluttering the interface?

Comment: I agree that a way of stopping a scheduled mailing from going out that enabled the user to make changes and then restart the mailing would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pretty, but you can use the API from your browser to un-schedule the mailing.

1. Find the ID of your mailing

   1. Go to **Mailings > Scheduled and Sent Mailings**
   2. Find your scheduled or canceled mailing within the list
   3. Determine the ID of the mailing by hovering over **Report** and looking for the number after `mid=` in the URL
2. Open a javascript console in your web browser

   1. Begin with your web browser on any CiviCRM page.
   2. In Firefox go to menu > "Developer" > "Web Console". In Chrome, go to menu > "More tools" > "Developer Tools" > "Console".
   3. If you can type `2+2`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and see `4`, you're all set.
3. Execute some API commands to un-schedule the mailing

   1. Copy-paste the following code into the console (but don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet)

      ```
      var mailingID = 0;
      CRM.api3('MailingJob', 'get', {'mailing_id': mailingID}).done(
        function(response) {
          CRM.api3('MailingJob', 'delete', {'id': response.id});
        }
      );
      CRM.api3('Mailing', 'create',
        {'id': mailingID, 'scheduled_id': '', 'scheduled_date': ''});
      ```
   2. Update the number 0 after `mailingID` to your own ID value determined above.
   3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the commands.
4. See the results

   1. Go to **Mailings > Draft and Unscheduled Mailings** and find your mailing here, waiting for you to **Continue**